# Group Items in Itemtemplate

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-templates

If this question is already answered, please point me to the correct answer. I haven't found a similar question here.

I have created an Itemtemplate with two files, which need grouping after adding them to a project.

Is it possible to add an attribute or similar to the template-definition?

So far I've following code in the MyTemplate.vstemplate-file:

```
.......     
<TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">filename.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.Properties.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">filename.Properties.cs</ProjectItem>
</TemplateContent>
.......
```

I know (from Stackoverflow ;-) ) how to group files manually after the adding in the Project-Explorer and this is not the answer I'm looking for.

I hope anybody knows the answer to this.

Comment: Not any Idieas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to try this way:

```
<TemplateContent>
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">filename.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs\$fileinputname$.Properties.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">filename.Properties.cs</ProjectItem>
</TemplateContent>
```

I've found the solution [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247115%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (see the "Community Additions" section). Thus sometimes comments are more useful than an original article (especially about VS templates).

Comment: Yes that looks like it ist the answer to my question. I think it's a shame that such things aren't propper documented.